# Call a javascript function from anchor tag inside td inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Only Basic javascript knowledge is required.If anyone knows please help me.**
I don't know how to do it but i have tried it in many ways but still not able to pass the value.

Simply, i have a for loop and i have a td inside it. I want to call a javascript function from this td click but problem is **i am unable to pass any parameter to this function.**

the code is here :

```
 function GetContractList(abc) {
  var data = abc
  for (var it in data) {
            tab += "<tr>";
            tab += "<td>" + data[it].ContractCode + "</td>";
            if (data[it].ContractCode != "") {
                var Contract = data[it].ContractCode;
                 tab += "<td><a onclick='Delete_User(Contract);'>View</td>";
               // tab += "<td><a data=" + data[it].ContractCode + " href='javascript:Delete_User(this.data);'>View</td>";
            }
            else {
                tab += "<td></td>";
            }
```

As u can see, i have tried to pass parameter to Delete_User function but the syntax is somewhere broken.

```
  tab += "<td><a onclick='Delete_User(Contract);'>View</td>";
```

this line gives error-- Contract is not defined.

```
"<td><a data=" + data[it].ContractCode + " href='javascript:Delete_User(this.data);'>View</td>".
```

This line also doesnot passes any value to the function.
Please someone help me out.

Comment: you are missing a closing anchor tag

Comment: @NinaScholz problem is not with closing a tag, if i put it still it doesnot work

Comment: Contract is a variable...you are passing it as string. Look in generated html

Comment: The Contract object cannot be accessible by the click handler as you are creating it in another block. Show us your complete code and we will see how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quote for the parameter of the function.

```
tab += '<td><a href="javascript:Delete_User(\'' + data[it].ContractCode + '\');">View</a></td>';
//                                          ^^                             ^^
```

```js
function Delete_User(id) {
    console.log('Delete_User', id);
}

var cc = '4711abc',
    tab = '<a href="javascript:Delete_User(\'' + cc + '\');">View</a>';

document.write(tab);
```

Comment: `<a href="javascript:Delete_User(" ' + data[it].contractcode= ' ');'>View</a>`   I have used as u said but generated html is like this

Comment: what is `=` and `+=` doing in your string?

Comment: in single loop call , it is appending data to same tr with mutliple td one by one. and my page is razor page used in asp.net mvc so although ur code is working fine in sample given by u but on my code, it is generating some other html. dont know whether i have explained u everthing right or not

Answer (score 0):

try:
`var cont = data[it].ContractCode.replace(/"/g, '\\"');`
`tab += '<td><a onclick="Delete_User(\''+cont+'\');">View</td>";`

first line encodes any double quotes
the second line inserts the contract as a parameter and adds single quotes around it